# Background-image rendered too late on Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome

The problem is after I add a class to my button element using JavaScript, the background image (.gif) that should display after the change, is rendered much too late.

The button is a form submit. After being clicked, a class "clicked" is added to it inside JavaScript. CSS style says that the button with a class "clicked" should display a background-image loader animation. And it does, but somehow late (0.5-1.0s after a click), usually not even making it before the page is re-loaded after a submit. I paused JavaScript after the class is added and inspected the DOM inside developer tools. The class is already added then, but the image usually (sometimes it is) is not displayed.

Here's a fiddle mimicking that behavior: http://codepen.io/rjk/pen/rGntD

The problem is present on the Chrome browser. Firefox displays everything instantly, just as it should.

Does somebody knows how to force Chrome to display the change instantly and remove this nondeterminism?

---

My JavaScript (after some simplification) looks like this:

```
function loadingClickHandle(button, style) {
  jQuery(button).addClass(style + "-clicked");
}

loadingClickHandle(this, "button-blue");
$("form:first").submit();
```

Comment: you may preload this backgound with background:-norepeat;background-position:100% 100%; and replace background-position in view via your class

Comment: use a compressed image

Comment: Setting background-repeat and background-position inside JavaScript didn't help. My image is animation, so I can't use any other format than .gif.

Comment: do it inside both classes , did you understand the idea, image is already here , no need to load it on request just reset background-position/repeat :) can you put your try into a codepen or fiddle on line , so we see what you've down ?

Comment: if the image is small enough you can try converting it to base64 string and embed it in css file itself, that way browser doesn't has to load the image file from server when required.

Comment: @GCyrillus I'm not sure if I got your idea, but what I did is explicitly set *background-position* and *background-repeat* inside the JavaScript soon after the class is added using this 2 instructions: "button.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat"; button.style.backgroundPosition = "100% 100%";".

Comment: @Robert can you show us the javascript/css you're using?

Comment: @webkit I added the JavaScript in the main post.

Comment: you commented above that you are adding the styles via javascript.. here you are adding a CSS class.. where's the CSS?

Comment: @Robert these rules should be before the js is activated, and once javscript/class is added , then reset background-position/repeat. the rule given hides it but loads it

Comment: @robert, jyste make a fiddle with some dummy image http://dummyimage.com/100x100

Comment: @webkit, I posted my original JavaScript code. Now I added the 2 lines I wrote after GCyrillus advise.

Comment: hmmmm okay: here a basic fiddle with a button and jQuery : http://jsfiddle.net/GCyrillus/Ckg6W/ , so what does your try looks alike ? can provide yourself a jsfiddle with the code having issue described ?

Comment: I'm trying to make a fiddle. Will post it as soon as I'm done.

Comment: @Robert you're issue is chrome specific.. meaning there's something wrong with your code, or there's a bug.. to understand what it is, we need to see the whole picture.. (css+html+js).. in your example above, you are adding a css class with jquery, why are you than not using that class in your css to invoke the styles instead of writing them in js a line after? Also if you are using jquery why not use the syntax for writing in styles? usually with loaders the bg position would be 50% 50%, but again, i need to see the REST of your code ;)

Comment: @webkit I don't force any style in JavaScript. The lines I added here, were only to show you how I implemented the GCyrillus suggestion about explicitly setting *background-position* and *background-repeat* which I may have not undestood right.

I'm in the middle of writing a fiddle, but it's not that easy, taking the very messy structure of the original project I'm working on. Let me only tell you that the original project uses a JavaScript embedded into an XSL transform with external JS and CSS files...

Comment: Alright, here's a fiddle: http://codepen.io/rjk/pen/rGntD

Comment: The image URL was wrong but I've already corrected it.

Comment: I made a few minor changes, but in the currrent state it's exactly mimicking my page's behavior. When my Firefox displays the icon instantly (even before the "class added" alert is shown), Chrome fails to display it at all before the page is reloaded.

Comment: Actually, your button is in a form and once click , form is submited, it refreshes/reload the whole thing and reinitialized CSS/JS see it outside a form http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/LBFvq

Comment: I wrote at the beginning that it's a form submit. But anyway, it takes a while (and in my page/application it takes quite a while) between the button is clicked and the form is actually submitted. I want the image to show during that second or two. In Firefox it actually work flawlessly - the loader image shows as soon as the button is clicked. I still don't see why Chrome shouldn't do the same.

Also that's why I made that "alert('class added');" line in my pen. Notice that when the alert shows, the class is already added and the image should also be already displayed. Firefox displays it.

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/tskGh ?

Comment: @Prashank, I must say I've tried your solution (base64 string) as soon as you suggested it, but base64 strings raised problems with wro4j's css minimizer I'm using and I abandoned the idea. Now as you showed me a working pen, I've worked out the wro4j issue and implemented base64 strings on my page. It works just fine on Chrome. So thank you very much! You can also post it as a solution, since so far it's the only one that works. I don't like that much the idea of littering my CSS code with those 1000+ character strings, but using SASS let me work around that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution to convert the image to base64 string. That way the browser doesn't have to request the image from server which creates a delay.

I would say that its only a good idea if you have small image, because base64 encoding increases the size of the data...

> Very roughly, the final size of Base64-encoded binary data is equal to 1.37 times the original data size + 814 bytes (for headers).

Source http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64

Based on your provided code

```
.blue-button {
  background-color: #1b9bdd;
  color: white;
  height: 30px;
  padding-left: 14px;
  padding-right: 14px;
}

.blue-button.clicked {
  background-image: url(data:image/gif;base64,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);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  color: transparent;
}
```

Demo [HERE](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/tskGh)

Tool used to convert image is [HERE](http://webcodertools.com/imagetobase64converter)